# Spring: Why is setter not called in spite of @Autowired annotation

Tags: java, spring

I am learning Spring. I came around using Spring with JDBC and also read about Autowiring.

So I wrote this

```
public class JdbcAccess {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        System.out.println("setDataSource called");
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public void getCount1() {
        String sql= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE";
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
        jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        int count = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql);      
        System.out.println("Result is = " + count);
    }

    public void getCount2() {
        String sql= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE";
        int count = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql);        // Line 66
        System.out.println("Count = " + count);
    }
}
```

I expect below as output:

```
setDataSource called
Count = 3
```

What I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at playwithspring.JdbcAccess.getCount2(JdbcAccess.java:66)
```

This means `setDataSource(..)`, isn't being called by Spring, but Spring framework is setting the data source correctly, because `getCount1()`, which makes a call to `getDataSource()` runs fine. So my questions are:

- Then **how is Spring setting dataSource** without calling setter ?
- **What I can do** in above program **to achieve** desired **output** ?

**Please note:** I run either `getCount1()` or `getCount2()`

Comment: Why should it? It is on the field and tha tis injected directly into the field not using the setter. If you want the setter to be called put `@Autowired` on the setter.

Comment: oh.. I was not aware that Spring can inject directly... my bad.. Thanks !

Comment: @M.Deinum But then by any chance, can you tell me how does it inject directly.. I mean how does Spring access private fields and sets them ?

Comment: Using reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the exception is because your `setDataSource` is not called as Spring uses reflection for setting the data source.

You have two good options to set it, either annotate your setter method with @Autowired or you could leave your current annotation on the dataSource variable and use @PostConstruct annotation to initialize your `jdbcTemplate` which I think would lead to a cleaner code.

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    System.out.println("jdbTemplate created");
}

public void getCount2() {
   String sql= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE";
   int count = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql);
   System.out.println("Count = " + count);
}
```

Comment: I liked the idea of PostConsruct !

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

**Field Injection**

```
@Autowired
 private DataSource dataSource;
```

**USE Setter Injection** instead of Field injection if you want setter to be called.

```
@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        System.out.println("setDataSource called");
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

Comment: Of course because in my solution I'm using setter injection.